# botocore.exceptions.ClientError:(ValidationException)PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key media in the item

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to put data to dynamodb table name=media_info and the partition_key = media

and i have data in .json file,while putting data i am getting above error

```
import boto3
import os
import requests
import tqdm
import json
dynamo_client  =  boto3.resource(service_name = 'dynamodb',region_name = 'ap-south-1',
              aws_access_key_id = '*****************',
              aws_secret_access_key = '***********************')


product_table = dynamo_client.Table('media_info')
data = open('outputfile.json')

data = json.load(data)
data = {'name':data} 

response=product_table.put_item(Item=data)
```

and data is:

```
{"statusCode": 200, "body": "{\"message\": \"{\\\"tracks\\\": [{\\\"track_type\\\": \\\"General\\\", \\\"count\\\": \\\"332\\\", \\\"count_of_stream_of_this_kind\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\\"kind_of_stream\\\": \\\"General\\\", \\\"other_kind_of_stream\\\": [\\\"General\\\"], \\\"stream_identifier\\\": \\\"0\\\", \\\"count_of_video_streams\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\\"count_of_audio_streams\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\\"video_format_list\\\": \\\"AVC\\\", \\\"video_format_withhint_list\\\": \\\"AVC\\\", \\\"codecs_video\\\": \\\"AVC\\\", \\\"audio_format_list\\\": \\\"AAC LC\\\", \\\"audio_format_withhint_list\\\": \\\"AAC LC\\\", \\\"audio_codecs\\\": \\\"AAC LC\\\", \\\"complete_name\\\": \\\"https://pymediainfo-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/oceans.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATZUNEARHO4A6K6EM%2F20230104%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230104T071236Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJ%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCmFwLXNvdXRoLTEiSDBGAiEAty6idG3BsESm08f93SSBspzBH98uVggsgba1kGU6Xw4CIQCyJcKrPJloUFkPFnhyxSF5El7WyUL1OT6RAwhendwWoyqEAwjo%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAAaDDI2MTIxNTIyNDkxMCIMFIfiFQsOK77hNT7xKtgCVosPbXnCfoI922bm7opDsI6d%2F6KuxfMtIF8TOaubLmpuaHf0tzJDWCRAVEiYjm4OrZdQuTMNYJldMjZaeMYmPPMCg8Ubj89NeCzn1GO6SDnsQ9DeUg%2BEIzn6XcJi75QpWTMa1OjcbM1yMfap4TVtkDShJ8tmdmS4RBwPVfw%2BrsEiVDlfIRCsrbRkjUEw4lxukof5lj6M%2B%2BeW3XB%2BhSqXk%2B9FFWpBMc01myafkz%2BTQeDPlVkMBoikvTMlrgqRF%2BOUbKvrLNBjD9Z3v6Xxotof43xXxR8Z1qQ%2Bt9ycv03W2ZRWbzplzFwvx3KC2ncY1VbenTza2QuW6oawOTfvnEmWDHXyj71E6UB%2FneUp%2BSIoVbXTHTlC4m5o8d1v75ZE5GeplsO75Budk79G4yRyWjYqQ7r66ZSRo9DMzp0mpqnhMFTPm8V5816Eld%2BpFf1bqcLedLk9iMPiyisw3s3UnQY6nQH4VcxonNIASjHkraUVmgOtKP0VzTKPVCx7a87z1j0dVO3KPA0T4Fc%2FJK40FALx%2FPMKA6W5kyj%2FGnoKugR1yJeOpjq4I0l92Pm6o%2B%2Flqc1SQXLQ9TXnqKeS%2BdVKqI8QFhqtL4zqV%2B3kOv27vZfFCW7WL4Be7jaLLIw%2Frplontsiq0vIAFv5AiaDOt5p3QeXm1NzZqfwZVFWUt1teoob&X-Amz-Signature=8b9837544236ea469c90c61d0dbb4e01fa3a5450e6fdf0b12ca9bcaee6a2309a\\\", \\\"folder_name\\\": \\\"https://pymediainfo-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos\\\", \\\"file_name_extension\\\": \\\"oceans.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATZUNEARHO4A6K6EM%2F20230104%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230104T071236Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJ%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCmFwLXNvdXRoLTEiSDBGAiEAty6idG3BsESm08f93SSBspzBH98uVggsgba1kGU6Xw4CIQCyJcKrPJloUFkPFnhyxSF5El7WyUL1OT6RAwhendwWoyqEAwjo%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAAaDDI2MTIxNTIyNDkxMCIMFIfiFQsOK77hNT7xKtgCVosPbXnCfoI922bm7opDsI6d%2F6KuxfMtIF8TOaubLmpuaHf0tzJDWCRAVEiYjm4OrZdQuTMNYJldMjZaeMYmPPMCg8Ubj89NeCzn1GO6SDnsQ9DeUg%2BEIzn6XcJi75QpWTMa1OjcbM1yMfap4TVtkDShJ8tmdmS4RBwPVfw%2BrsEiVDlfIRCsrbRkjUEw4lxukof5lj6M%2B%2BeW3XB%2BhSqXk%2B9FFWpBMc01myafkz%2BTQeDPlVkMBoikvTMlrgqRF%2BOUbKvrLNBjD9Z3v6Xxotof43xXxR8Z1qQ%2Bt9ycv03W2ZRWbzplzFwvx3KC2ncY1VbenTza2QuW6oawOTfvnEmWDHXyj71E6UB%2FneUp%2BSIoVbXTHTlC4m5o8d1v75ZE5GeplsO75Budk79G4yRyWjYqQ7r66ZSRo9DMzp0mpqnhMFTPm8V5816Eld%2BpFf1bqcLedLk9iMPiyisw3s3UnQY6nQH4VcxonNIASjHkraUVmgOtKP0VzTKPVCx7a87z1j0dVO3KPA0T4Fc%2FJK40FALx%2FPMKA6W5kyj%2FGnoKugR1yJeOpjq4I0l92Pm6o%2B%2Flqc1SQXLQ9TXnqKeS%2BdVKqI8QFhqtL4zqV%2B3kOv27vZfFCW7WL4Be7jaLLIw%2Frplontsiq0vIAFv5AiaDOt5p3QeXm1NzZqfwZVFWUt1teoob&X-Amz-Signature=8b9837544236ea469c90c61d0dbb4e01fa3a5450e6fdf0b12ca9bcaee6a2309a\\\", \\\"file_name\\\": \\\"oceans\\\", \\\"file_extension\\\": \\\"mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATZUNEARHO4A6K6EM%2F20230104%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230104T071236Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJ%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCmFwLXNvdXRoLTEiSDBGAiEAty6idG3BsESm08f93SSBspzBH98uVggsgba1kGU6Xw4CIQCyJcKrPJloUFkPFnhyxSF5El7WyUL1OT6RAwhendwWoyqEAwjo%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAAaDDI2MTIxNTIyNDkxMCIMFIfiFQsOK77hNT7xKtgCVosPbXnCfoI922bm7opDsI6d%2F6KuxfMtIF8TOaubLmpuaHf0tzJDWCRAVEiYjm4OrZdQuTMNYJldMjZaeMYmPPMCg8Ubj89NeCzn1GO6SDnsQ9DeUg%2BEIzn6XcJi75QpWTMa1OjcbM1yMfap4TVtkDShJ8tmdmS4RBwPVfw%2BrsEiVDlfIRCsrbRkjUEw4lxukof5lj6M%2B%2BeW3XB%2BhSqXk%2B9FFWpBMc01myafkz%2BTQeDPlVkMBoikvTMlrgqRF%2BOUbKvrLNBjD9Z3v6Xxotof43xXxR8Z1qQ%2Bt9ycv03W2ZRWbzplzFwvx3KC2ncY1VbenTza2QuW6oawOTfvnEmWDHXyj71E6UB%2FneUp%2BSIoVbXTHTlC4m5o8d1v75ZE5GeplsO75Budk79G4yRyWjYqQ7r66ZSRo9DMzp0mpqnhMFTPm8V5816Eld%2BpFf1bqcLedLk9iMPiyisw3s3UnQY6nQH4VcxonNIASjHkraUVmgOtKP0VzTKPVCx7a87z1j0dVO3KPA0T4Fc%2FJK40FALx%2FPMKA6W5kyj%2FGnoKugR1yJeOpjq4I0l92Pm6o%2B%2Flqc1SQXLQ9TXnqKeS%2BdVKqI8QFhqtL4zqV%2B3kOv27vZfFCW7WL4Be7jaLLIw%2Frplontsiq0vIAFv5AiaDOt5p3QeXm1NzZqfwZVFWUt1teoob&X-Amz-Signature=8b9837544236ea469c90c61d0dbb4e01fa3a5450e6fdf0b12ca9bcaee6a2309a\\\", \\\"format\\\": \\\"MPEG-4\\\", \\\"other_format\\\": [\\\"MPEG-4\\\"], \\\"format_extensions_usually_used\\\": \\\"braw mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p m4r 3ga 3gpa 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v\\\", \\\"commercial_name\\\": \\\"MPEG-4\\\", \\\"format_profile\\\": \\\"Base Media\\\", \\\"internet_media_type\\\": \\\"video/mp4\\\", \\\"codec_id\\\": \\\"isom\\\", \\\"other_codec_id\\\": [\\\"isom (isom/avc1)\\\"], \\\"codec_id_url\\\": \\\"http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/standalone.html\\\", \\\"codecid_compatible\\\": \\\"isom/avc1\\\", \\\"file_size\\\": 23014356, \\\"other_file_size\\\": [\\\"21.9 MiB\\\", \\\"22 MiB\\\", \\\"22 MiB\\\", \\\"21.9 MiB\\\", \\\"21.95 MiB\\\"], \\\"duration\\\": 46613, \\\"other_duration\\\": [\\\"46 s 613 ms\\\", \\\"46 s 613 ms\\\", \\\"46 s 613 ms\\\", \\\"00:00:46.613\\\", \\\"00:00:46;12\\\", \\\"00:00:46.613 (00:00:46;12)\\\"], \\\"overall_bit_rate_mode\\\": \\\"VBR\\\", \\\"other_overall_bit_rate_mode\\\": [\\\"Variable\\\"], \\\"overall_bit_rate\\\": 3949861, \\\"other_overall_bit_rate\\\": [\\\"3 950 kb/s\\\"], \\\"frame_rate\\\": \\\"23.976\\\", \\\"other_frame_rate\\\": [\\\"23.976 FPS\\\"], \\\"frame_count\\\": \\\"1116\\\", \\\"stream_size\\\": 16342, \\\"other_stream_size\\\": [\\\"16.0 KiB (0%)\\\", \\\"16 KiB\\\", \\\"16 KiB\\\", \\\"16.0 KiB\\\", \\\"15.96 KiB\\\", \\\"16.0 KiB (0%)\\\"], \\\"proportion_of_this_stream\\\": \\\"0.00071\\\", \\\"headersize\\\": \\\"16334\\\", \\\"datasize\\\": \\\"22998022\\\", \\\"footersize\\\": \\\"0\\\", \\\"isstreamable\\\": \\\"Yes\\\", \\\"encoded_date\\\": \\\"UTC 2013-05-03 22:51:07\\\", \\\"tagged_date\\\": \\\"UTC 2013-05-03 22:51:07\\\", \\\"fileextension_invalid\\\": \\\"braw mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p m4r 3ga 3gpa 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v\\\"}, {\\\"track_type\\\": \\\"Video\\\", \\\"count\\\": \\\"378\\\", \\\"count_of_stream_of_this_kind\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\\"kind_of_stream\\\": \\\"Video\\\", \\\"other_kind_of_stream\\\": [\\\"Video\\\"], \\\"stream_identifier\\\": \\\"0\\\", \\\"streamorder\\\": \\\"0\\\", \\\"track_id\\\": 1, \\\"other_track_id\\\": [\\\"1\\\"], \\\"format\\\": \\\"AVC\\\", \\\"other_format\\\": [\\\"AVC\\\"], \\\"format_info\\\": \\\"Advanced Video Codec\\\", \\\"format_url\\\": \\\"http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html\\\", \\\"commercial_name\\\": \\\"AVC\\\", \\\"format_profile\\\": \\\"Baseline@L3\\\", \\\"format_settings\\\": \\\"3 Ref Frames\\\", \\\"format_settings__cabac\\\": \\\"No\\\", \\\"other_format_settings__cabac\\\": [\\\"No\\\"], \\\"format_settings__reference_frames\\\": 3, \\\"other_format_settings__reference_frames\\\": [\\\"3 frames\\\"], \\\"internet_media_type\\\": \\\"video/H264\\\", \\\"codec_id\\\": \\\"avc1\\\", \\\"codec_id_info\\\": \\\"Advanced Video Coding\\\", \\\"duration\\\": 46545, \\\"other_duration\\\": [\\\"46 s 545 ms\\\", \\\"46 s 545 ms\\\", \\\"46 s 545 ms\\\", \\\"00:00:46.545\\\", \\\"00:00:46;12\\\", \\\"00:00:46.545 (00:00:46;12)\\\"], \\\"bit_rate\\\": 3859631, \\\"other_bit_rate\\\": [\\\"3 860 kb/s\\\"], \\\"maximum_bit_rate\\\": 9263280, \\\"other_maximum_bit_rate\\\": [\\\"9 263 kb/s\\\"], \\\"width\\\": 960, \\\"other_width\\\": [\\\"960 pixels\\\"], \\\"height\\\": 400, \\\"other_height\\\": [\\\"400 pixels\\\"], \\\"sampled_width\\\": \\\"960\\\", \\\"sampled_height\\\": \\\"400\\\", \\\"pixel_aspect_ratio\\\": \\\"1.000\\\", \\\"display_aspect_ratio\\\": \\\"2.400\\\", \\\"other_display_aspect_ratio\\\": [\\\"2.40:1\\\"], \\\"rotation\\\": \\\"0.000\\\", \\\"frame_rate_mode\\\": \\\"CFR\\\", \\\"other_frame_rate_mode\\\": [\\\"Constant\\\"], \\\"frame_rate\\\": \\\"23.976\\\", \\\"other_frame_rate\\\": [\\\"23.976 (24000/1001) FPS\\\"], \\\"framerate_num\\\": \\\"24000\\\", \\\"framerate_den\\\": \\\"1001\\\", \\\"frame_count\\\": \\\"1116\\\", \\\"color_space\\\": \\\"YUV\\\", \\\"chroma_subsampling\\\": \\\"4:2:0\\\", \\\"other_chroma_subsampling\\\": [\\\"4:2:0\\\"], \\\"bit_depth\\\": 8, \\\"other_bit_depth\\\": [\\\"8 bits\\\"], \\\"scan_type\\\": \\\"Progressive\\\", \\\"other_scan_type\\\": [\\\"Progressive\\\"], \\\"bits__pixel_frame\\\": \\\"0.419\\\", \\\"stream_size\\\": 22456564, \\\"other_stream_size\\\": [\\\"21.4 MiB (98%)\\\", \\\"21 MiB\\\", \\\"21 MiB\\\", \\\"21.4 MiB\\\", \\\"21.42 MiB\\\", \\\"21.4 MiB (98%)\\\"], \\\"proportion_of_this_stream\\\": \\\"0.97576\\\", \\\"writing_library\\\": \\\"Zencoder Video Encoding System\\\", \\\"other_writing_library\\\": [\\\"Zencoder Video Encoding System\\\"], \\\"encoded_library_name\\\": \\\"Zencoder Video Encoding System\\\", \\\"encoded_date\\\": \\\"UTC 2013-05-03 22:50:47\\\", \\\"tagged_date\\\": \\\"UTC 2013-05-03 22:51:08\\\", \\\"codec_configuration_box\\\": \\\"avcC\\\"}, {\\\"track_type\\\": \\\"Audio\\\", \\\"count\\\": \\\"280\\\", \\\"count_of_stream_of_this_kind\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\\"kind_of_stream\\\": \\\"Audio\\\", \\\"other_kind_of_stream\\\": [\\\"Audio\\\"], \\\"stream_identifier\\\": \\\"0\\\", \\\"streamorder\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\\"track_id\\\": 2, \\\"other_track_id\\\": [\\\"2\\\"], \\\"format\\\": \\\"AAC\\\", \\\"other_format\\\": [\\\"AAC LC\\\"], \\\"format_info\\\": \\\"Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity\\\", \\\"commercial_name\\\": \\\"AAC\\\", \\\"format_settings__sbr\\\": \\\"No (Explicit)\\\", \\\"other_format_settings__sbr\\\": [\\\"No (Explicit)\\\"], \\\"format_additionalfeatures\\\": \\\"LC\\\", \\\"codec_id\\\": \\\"mp4a-40-2\\\", \\\"duration\\\": 46613, \\\"other_duration\\\": [\\\"46 s 613 ms\\\", \\\"46 s 613 ms\\\", \\\"46 s 613 ms\\\", \\\"00:00:46.613\\\", \\\"00:00:46:23\\\", \\\"00:00:46.613 (00:00:46:23)\\\"], \\\"bit_rate_mode\\\": \\\"VBR\\\", \\\"other_bit_rate_mode\\\": [\\\"Variable\\\"], \\\"bit_rate\\\": 92920, \\\"other_bit_rate\\\": [\\\"92.9 kb/s\\\"], \\\"maximum_bit_rate\\\": 104944, \\\"other_maximum_bit_rate\\\": [\\\"105 kb/s\\\"], \\\"channel_s\\\": 2, \\\"other_channel_s\\\": [\\\"2 channels\\\"], \\\"channel_positions\\\": \\\"Front: L R\\\", \\\"other_channel_positions\\\": [\\\"2/0/0\\\"], \\\"channel_layout\\\": \\\"L R\\\", \\\"samples_per_frame\\\": \\\"1024\\\", \\\"sampling_rate\\\": 48000, \\\"other_sampling_rate\\\": [\\\"48.0 kHz\\\"], \\\"samples_count\\\": \\\"2237424\\\", \\\"frame_rate\\\": \\\"46.875\\\", \\\"other_frame_rate\\\": [\\\"46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)\\\"], \\\"frame_count\\\": \\\"2185\\\", \\\"compression_mode\\\": \\\"Lossy\\\", \\\"other_compression_mode\\\": [\\\"Lossy\\\"], \\\"stream_size\\\": 541450, \\\"other_stream_size\\\": [\\\"529 KiB (2%)\\\", \\\"529 KiB\\\", \\\"529 KiB\\\", \\\"529 KiB\\\", \\\"528.8 KiB\\\", \\\"529 KiB (2%)\\\"], \\\"proportion_of_this_stream\\\": \\\"0.02353\\\", \\\"encoded_date\\\": \\\"UTC 2013-05-03 22:51:07\\\", \\\"tagged_date\\\": \\\"UTC 2013-05-03 22:51:08\\\"}]}\"}"}
```

Comment: What is not clear? You are missing required keys as specified in the error message. Add those keys then.

Comment: I don't even know which question to pick as a duplicate target, because there are soo many.

Comment: can you tell me what i need to change

Comment: The error message very clearly tells you that the item you're putting into the table needs to have a key with the name `media` your item only has the key `name` thus DynamoDB is unhappy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValidationException while doing PutItem: Missing the key in the item: ClientError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240958/validationexception-while-doing-putitem-missing-the-key-in-the-item-clienterro)

Answer (score 0):

Your data now looks like the following:

```
{
 'name': # your payload from the file you read
    {
      "statusCode": 200, 
      "body":.....
    }
}
```

But should look like:

```
{
 'name': # your payload from the file you read
    {
      "statusCode": 200, 
      "body":.....
    }, 
  'media': 'some-unique-id' # your partition key which DynamoDB needs as top level attribute
}
```

Your item must always have `media` as a top level attribute as it is used as your partition key.

try:

```
data = json.load(data)
data = {'name':data, 'media':'media-1'}
```

Comment: it is working now ,but now data is visible on dynamodb

Comment: That's what usually happens when you write data to DynamoDB? What do you want to happen?